# member is private, operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++

I want to create class of cards, where I have method print and overloading operators(comparison of cards)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

enum Face {Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen,King, Ace};
enum Suit {Hearts,Clubs,Diamonds,Spades};

class Card{
private:
    Face face;
    Suit suit;

public:
    Card();
    Card(const Face face,const Suit suit);
    void print();
    friend bool operator>(Card& lhs,Card&rhs);
    friend bool operator==(Card& lhs,Card& rhs);
    friend bool operator!=(Card& lhs,Card& rhs);
    friend bool operator<(Card& lhs,Card& rhs);

};

const char* to_string_1(const Face value)
{
    const char* LUT[] = {"Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };
    return LUT[value];
}

const char* to_string_2(const Suit value)
{
    const char* LUT[] = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades" };
    return LUT[value];
}



Card::Card(){
}

Card::Card(Face rank_card,Suit suit_card){
    face = rank_card;
    suit = suit_card;
}




void Card::print(){
    cout << to_string_1(face) << " " <<  to_string_2(suit);
}



bool operator==(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs){
    if(lhs.face == rhs.face && lhs.suit == rhs.suit) return true;
    return false;
}

bool operator!=(const Card& lhs,const Card& rhs){
    if(lhs.face != rhs.face || lhs.suit != rhs.suit) return true;
    return false;
}

bool operator>(const Card& lhs,const Card& rhs){
    if(lhs.face > rhs.face && lhs.suit > rhs.suit) return true;
    if(lhs.face > rhs.face && lhs.suit == rhs.suit) return true;
    if(lhs.face == rhs.face && lhs.suit > rhs.suit) return true;
    return false;
}

bool operator<(const Card& lhs,const Card& rhs){
    if(lhs.face < rhs.face && lhs.suit < rhs.suit) return true;
    if(lhs.face < rhs.face && lhs.suit == rhs.suit) return true;
    if(lhs.face == rhs.face && lhs.suit < rhs.suit) return true;
    return false;
}

int main(){
    Card c_1(Two,Clubs);
    Card c_2(Five,Diamonds);
    c_2.print();
}
```

The problem is, that compiler throws me errors, such that:

12:10: error: 'Face Card::face' is private
58:24: error: within this context
13:10: error: 'Suit Card::suit' is private
58:36: error: within this context

But I defined operators as "friend" functions. Why does the programm stil complain?

Comment: Friend declarations are missing `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the friend and the declaration have to match exactly. Compare

```
friend bool operator>(Card& lhs,Card&rhs);
```

to

```
bool operator>(const Card& lhs,const Card& rhs){
```

You forgot your `const` in your friend declaration.